# Youtube API v3 missing "creation date" in request

Tags: php, youtube-api, request

I'm trying to make Youtube v3 Data API work on my website.

I shamelessly copied [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#search_by_keyword) code from google's code samples, and it is not working. The error message showed is this:

> An client error occurred: All cacheable requests must have creation dates.

I previously had issues with API keys as I forgot almost everything about APIs in general and I just thought this sample would have been useful to remember things. I managed to generate the appropriate key and now I know for sure it isn't the real problem.

Sadly Google didn't find posts related to this issue, except two links to the actual [Php Library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) that I implemented in my site to make everything work. By looking at it closely I noticed a developer comment that could be useful.

```
$rawDate = $resp->getResponseHeader('date');
$parsedDate = strtotime($rawDate);
if (empty($rawDate) || false == $parsedDate) {
  // We can't default this to now, as that means future cache reads
  // will always pass with the logic below, so we will require a
  // date be injected if not supplied.
  throw new Google_Exception("All cacheable requests must have creation dates.");
}
```

I can understand english pretty well but I really don't know what to do now.
I even tried to add some sort of date in the request in my code, but it isn't working (you can laugh):

```
 // Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified
// query term.
$searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
  'q' => $_GET['q'],
  'maxResults' => $_GET['maxResults'],
  'date' => strtotime(),
));
```

> An client error occurred: (list) unknown parameter: 'date'

Any tips? Thank you in advance

EDIT: I know, this PHP library is currently in beta, but there must be some workaround.

EDIT 2: I found a temporary work around. I inverted the logic gate of that 'if' in the Php Library and now it works. But I don't like doing this, and I won't mark this as solved. At least if you know the reason of the bug please explain it to me, I'm really interested.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the latest version of the client library? How are you implementing that code in your website?

Comment: When I posted this (22 Aug) I was already using the latest version. The last time they modified something was the 20th of August, as you can see on GitHub. If my page is showing a specific error it means that I managed to include correctly the .php files:
 `require_once 'myLibrary/autoload.php';
require_once 'myLibrary/src/Google/Client.php';
require_once myLibrary/src/Google/Service/YouTube.php';` 
Now I'm wondering if the php of my host is bugged. I checked with phpinfo() and I have 5.3.10, and on GitHub they say you need at least 5.3, so I should be fine.
P.S. I have the code in index.php.